# How do I convert a regex with pack and hex from Perl to Python?

Tags: python, perl

I am a newcomer to Python and am converting a Perl script.  What is the Python equivalent to...

```
$value =~ s/%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Porting code this way - line by line - will surely end in an abomination

Answer (score 1):

You should likely just use [urllib.unquote](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html) (python 2) / [urllib.parse.unquote](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/urllib.parse.html) (python 3), since it looks like that's what the code you provided is trying to accomplish.

Comment: Indeed, the code snippet appears here http://www.cgi101.com/class/ch4/text.html for example

Answer (score 0):

```
value = value.decode('hex')
```